# Bootstrap3 sticky footer overlaps reactive content

Tags: html, css, r, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap in conjunction with Shiny and R. But this doesn't really matter, because Shiny just uses a normal bootstrap installation.

So my footer is coded like this:

```
/* Sticky Footer */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
/* End Sticky Footer
```

And basically it works nicely. What doesn't work is the resizing I guess after all content is loaded. Since R computes a lot in the background even after the HTML code etc. is loaded, the size of the page usually gets quite bigger after loading. But then my sticky footer overlaps the content and I have been struggling with this now all day and haven't found a solution yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `position: static` in your footer CSS class

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="main-content">

</div>

<footer>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body,html {
height: 100%;
}

body {
min-height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

#main-content {
background-color: red;
height: 1000px;
width: 100%;
}

footer {
clear: both;
position: static;
bottom: 0;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
background-color: blue;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/a5xtu95z/

I don't have much experience with bootstrap but I can't see why this wont work?

Answer (score -1):

Please try this reference link for the Sticky footer layout
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
/* Margin bottom by footer height */
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
     height: 60px;
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```